# Is nullptr available?

Tags: c++, c++11, nullptr

In C++ is there a way to check that the `nullptr` keyword is available? Or can you check that C++11 is supported?

I would like a way like this:

`#ifndef c++11`

`#define nullptr 0`

Comment: which compiler you're using? which version?

Comment: Code::Blocks and Visual Studio! But the best is something crossplatform

Comment: +1 Good to know if can check C++ lib version.